# WAS 6.0 startup failing: NoClassDefFound for ibmorb.jar

Tags: websphere

When I am trying to start my WAS server using eclipse, I am getting the following exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/ext/ibmorb/jar;C:/Program
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files.IBM.WebSphere.AppServer.java.jre.lib.ext.ibmorb.jar;C:.Program
```

I think the problem will be resolved when we place the jar in the path. If yes, please let me know from where can I get the jar file.

Thanks in advance,
Karthik.

Answer (score 1):

How are you starting it? I would start the app server from it's command line /bin/startServer **server1**

Once i know that things are working well, i will look at troubleshooting stuff. ibmorb.jar is a pretty important file and i don't see how they could go missing.

They should typically be in the jre/lib directory.

From the logs that you have i suspect there are some issues. Notice

*Files/IBM/WebSphere...* in your error message.

"C:/Program Files" is not present in that structure. I suspect the space in Program Files is giving you trouble.  Try using the 8 char notation c:/Progra~1 in your eclipse config of WebSphere and see if that helps over come this issue.

Try these only after you get the server starting on its own (outside eclipse) to ensure that your WAS set up is good and running.

HTH

Manglu